# Emacs: projectile-toggle-between-implementation-and-test for TypeScript spec file discovery

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-projectile

I really enjoyed using this projectile function in other languages but I'm currently having a hard time trying to figure out a way to set it for a typical TypeScript project.

```sh
ls services/
foo.service.ts foo.service.spec.ts bar.ts bar.spec.ts
```

When I execute `projectile-toggle-between-implementation-and-test` in any of these 4 files I get the following error:

```
helm-M-x-execute-command: No matching test file found for project type ‘npm’
```

In other words, the rule is `try to find a file in the same directory with/without *.spec.ts* suffix`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is pretty simple. You need to evaluate the following snippet(notice the npm project-type):

```lisp
(defun projectile-test-suffix (project-type)
  "Find default test files suffix based on PROJECT-TYPE."
  (cond
   ((member project-type '(emacs-cask)) "-test")
   ((member project-type '(rails-rspec ruby-rspec)) "_spec")
   ((member project-type '(rails-test ruby-test lein-test boot-clj go)) "_test")
   ((member project-type '(scons)) "test")
   ((member project-type '(npm)) ".spec")
   ((member project-type '(maven symfony)) "Test")
   ((member project-type '(gradle gradlew grails)) "Spec")))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript, but it might be a better idea to define some TS project type if it can identified based on its file structure.